# How do I set up wiki.js as a private wiki?

Tags: permissions

Just need wiki.js for a small number of users, but would like to make it a private wiki. Any suggestions or links to resources on how to do this?

Answer (score 24):

In wiki.js, unauthenticated users receive the permissions assigned to the "Guests" group.

To make it private, go into `Administration Area / Users / Groups`, select Guests and in the Permissions tab uncheck everything and save.

Afterwards everyone visiting your wiki will be required to login as an registered user.

Comment: It works perfectly as suggested. Thanks so much for your help.  I didn't realize unregistered visitors to the wiki were assigned as Guest by default.